# Jquery: when click on input/textarea/select/checkbox/ add a css background to the next field name

Tags: jquery

Its hard to explain into words but on this form

http://jsfiddle.net/6SEtr/3/

How can i express in jquery that whenever user clicks on input or textarea or select or checkbox (basically all the form options) i want to add a #FF9 background the next field name.

Example: if user clicks on the first select, then "Fecha" gets the background, if click on the second select, * Pago: gets the background, if clicks on the first input, then "Localidad" gets the background etc.

Its basically to push the users to go on the next field highlighting the next one, hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

http://jsfiddle.net/6SEtr/8/

**Code**

```
$(function(){
    $("input, select, textarea").focus(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").next().find("td:first").css("backgroundColor", "#FF9");
    }).blur(function(){
       $(this).closest("tr").next().find("td:first").css("backgroundColor", "");
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':input').focus(function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('strong').css('background-color','#ff9');
}).blur(function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('strong').css('background-color','');
});
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6SEtr/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just set a click handler on each input or select.

```
    $("input, select").click( function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").next().find("input, select").css("background-color","#f00")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input, select, textarea').click(function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil('tr').parent().next().find('td:has(strong) strong').css('background', '#FF9');
}).blur(function() {
    $('strong').css('background', '');
});
```